Use java enum in graphql schema with different values
I have java enum
public enum JavaStatus{
ACTIVE,
PAUSED,
STOPPPED;
}

I want to send and receive this enum through graphql with lowercase values. And frontend should be able to load graphl schema to check available values. So schema.graphqls should contain:
enum GraphqlStatus{
active
paused
stopped
}

How can I map it?
I tried
@Bean(name = "graphqlStatusEnum)
    public GraphQLEnumType graphqlStatusEnum() {
        return GraphQLEnumType.newEnum().name("GraphqlStatus")
                .value("active", JavaStatus.ACTIVE)
                .value("paused", JavaStatus.PAUSED)
                .value("stopped", JavaStatus.STOPPPED)
                .build();
    }

But I got error
Expected value for name 'active' in enum 'JavaStatus' but found none!



Add a custom EnumValuesProvider to the GraphQL wiring:
@Configuration
public class GraphQLConfig {
    @Bean
    public RuntimeWiringConfigurer runtimeWiringConfigurer() {
        return wiringBuilder -> wiringBuilder
                .type(newTypeWiring("GraphqlStatus")
                        .enumValues(graphqlStatusEnum())
                );
    }

    private EnumValuesProvider graphqlStatusEnum() {
        return new MapEnumValuesProvider(Map.of("active", JavaStatus.ACTIVE, "paused", JavaStatus.PAUSED, "stopped", JavaStatus.STOPPED));
    }
}



I thought that it is not important... I forgot to mention that I have this enum inside another class:
public class SomeProccess{
public JavaStatus status;
}
and schema.graphqls:
type SomeProccess{
status: GraphqlStatus
}
input SomeProccess{
status: GraphqlStatus
}

But now it looks like automatic mapping through field has higher priority than through RuntimeWiringConfigurer because I have the same error again.
I don't any wiring configuration in my GraphQLConfig class, so I think it works form the box. I use this libs:
implementation "com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphql-spring-boot-starter:15.0.0"
implementation "com.graphql-java-kickstart:playground-spring-boot-starter:11.1.0"

I meant I don't have any wiring configuration except RuntimeWiringConfigurer

@vanR I've never used com.graphql-java-kickstart:graphql-spring-boot-starter and it's not maintained anymore. But I tested it with org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-graphql and it's working even when enum field is inside another type. In your comment you have type and input with the same name which will cause errors if it is not a typo. Also I don't know what you mean by "automatic mapping through field", can you provide more details on your implementation?
